# Dual monitor problem in Debian

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, thinkpad, i915

I have a Lenovo laptop with Debian 10
Having it connected to 2 external monitors via a USB-C hub in one of them (DELL U2722DE).

Often when connecting to the hub one of the monitors do not connect properly. In this case it is the Phillips 241P6Q, but occasionally it is also the DELL monitor.

Please advise :)

See the syslog posted below:

````
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(4480, 1440)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  2
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary Output: false
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: true
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Old: QSize(2560, 1440)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Intermediate: QSize(4480, 1440)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:                 New: QSize(4480, 1440)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: true
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:                  (446)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: true
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:                  (447)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetScreenSize
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         DPI: 96.2526
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Size: QSize(4480, 1440)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         SizeMM: QSize(1182, 380)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetCrtcConfig (change output)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Output: 446 ( "DP-2-8" )
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Pos: QPoint(1920,0)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: 448 KScreen::Mode(Id: "448" , Size: QSize(2560, 1440) @ 59.9506 )
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Rotation: 1
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Result:  0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 446 update
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x55c7bc7ad600)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 448
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: QMap((63, XRandRCrtc(0x55c7bc7ad600))(64, XRandRCrtc(0x55c7bc7ade00))(65, XRandRCrtc(0x55c7bc7ade50)))
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: Testing CRTC 63
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Free: false
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: 448
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Possible outputs: QVector(66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 446, 447)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connected outputs: QVector(446)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Geometry: QRect(1920,0 2560x1440)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: Testing CRTC 64
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Free: true
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: 0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Possible outputs: QVector(66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 446, 447)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connected outputs: QVector()
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Geometry: QRect(0,120 0x0)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetCrtcConfig (enable output)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Output: 447 ( "DP-2-1" )
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         New CRTC: 64
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Pos: QPoint(0,132)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: KScreen::Mode(Id: "451" , Size: QSize(1920, 1080) @ 60 ) Preferred: "451"
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad org.kde.KScreen[1284]: kscreen.xrandr:         Rotation: 1
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: [drm:pipe_config_err [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in pixel_rate (expected 148500, found 296999)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: [drm:pipe_config_err [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in shared_dpll (expected 00000000b27df827, found 00000000f7cbbd8e)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: [drm:pipe_config_err [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in dpll_hw_state.ctrl1 (expected 0x00000003, found 0x00000001)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: [drm:pipe_config_err [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in base.adjusted_mode.crtc_clock (expected 148500, found 296999)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: [drm:pipe_config_err [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in port_clock (expected 270000, found 540000)
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: pipe state doesn't match!
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 860 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:11909 intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xcb3/0xd30 [i915]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: Modules linked in: cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii snd_usb_audio hid_generic snd_usbmidi_lib snd_rawmidi snd_seq_device usbhid hid ctr ccm rfcomm xfrm_user xfrm4_tunnel tunnel4 ipcomp xfrm_ipcomp esp4 ah4 af_key xfrm_algo l2tp_ppp l2tp_netlink l2tp_core ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel pppox ppp_generic slhc cmac bnep binfmt_misc fuse snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc intel_rapl snd_soc_sst_ipc btusb btrtl snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_hdmi btbcm uvcvideo snd_hda_ext_core btintel snd_soc_acpi_intel_match videobuf2_vmalloc snd_soc_acpi videobuf2_memops bluetooth x86_pkg_temp_thermal videobuf2_v4l2 nls_ascii snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_realtek videobuf2_common intel_powerclamp arc4 joydev snd_hda_codec_generic coretemp snd_compress iwlmvm jitterentropy_rng nls_cp437 kvm_intel videodev vfat sd_mod snd_hda_intel
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  drbg iTCO_wdt rmi_smbus fat sg mei_wdt kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul media crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel ansi_cprng intel_cstate ecdh_generic intel_uncore intel_rapl_perf wmi_bmof serio_raw rmi_core pcspkr mac80211 iTCO_vendor_support thinkpad_acpi snd_hda_codec battery ac nvram int3403_thermal snd_hda_core iwlwifi tpm_crb snd_hwdep snd_pcm cfg80211 tpm_tis snd_timer tpm_tis_core ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device pcc_cpufreq snd mei_me tpm typec_ucsi evdev rfkill int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone soundcore typec rng_core mei acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf i2c_dev parport_pc ppdev sunrpc lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb uas usb_storage scsi_mod i915 crc32c_intel aesni_intel i2c_algo_bit aes_x86_64
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  xhci_pci crypto_simd cryptd drm_kms_helper xhci_hcd glue_helper nvme psmouse e1000e drm usbcore i2c_i801 nvme_core usb_common thermal wmi video button
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 860 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W         4.19.0-23-rt-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.269-1
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20L6S0MD00/20L6S0MD00, BIOS N24ET56W (1.31 ) 02/19/2020
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RIP: 0010:intel_atomic_commit_tail+0xcb3/0xd30 [i915]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: Code: 0d 00 00 8d 71 41 48 c7 c7 08 22 5d c0 75 6c e8 b3 61 d5 ff e9 7c fb ff ff e8 79 35 3e e8 0f 0b e9 7c fd ff ff e8 6d 35 3e e8 <0f> 0b e9 44 fa ff ff e8 61 35 3e e8 0f 0b 0f b6 44 24 18 e9 76 f9
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb9a002337b48 EFLAGS: 00010286
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8be173e7a800 RCX: 0000000000000000
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffffa908aa7b RDI: 00000000ffffffff
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RBP: ffff8bdf131d7800 R08: 000000000000002c R09: 0000000000000004
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8bdf131d5800
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: R13: ffff8bdf131d3000 R14: ffff8be165490550 R15: ffff8be165490558
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: FS:  00007eff4f876f00(0000) GS:ffff8be1762c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: CR2: 00000d6d02090014 CR3: 00000002188da001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: Call Trace:
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  intel_atomic_commit+0x2a7/0x2e0 [i915]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x6e/0x80 [drm_kms_helper]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  drm_mode_setcrtc+0x18d/0x6d0 [drm]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x180/0x180 [drm]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xa1/0xf0 [drm]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x21e/0x3d0 [drm]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x180/0x180 [drm]
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa4/0x630
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  ? __schedule+0x32b/0x7b0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  ? __fget+0x8c/0xd0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  ksys_ioctl+0x60/0x90
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x16/0x20
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x5c/0xc1
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7eff4fda5fc7
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: Code: 00 00 90 48 8b 05 c9 9e 0c 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 99 9e 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffeee6f1128 EFLAGS: 00003246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffeee6f1160 RCX: 00007eff4fda5fc7
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RDX: 00007ffeee6f1160 RSI: 00000000c06864a2 RDI: 000000000000000e
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: RBP: 00007ffeee6f1160 R08: 0000000000000084 R09: 000055e782c9b8c0
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: R10: 00007ffeee6f1220 R11: 0000000000003246 R12: 00000000c06864a2
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: R13: 000000000000000e R14: 000055e7819b5440 R15: 0000000000000001
Apr 27 12:18:05 ghostpad kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000007 ]---```
````